# Verificar múltiplos input tipo Radio em um simulado

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, sql

Bem, estou criando um site e preciso validar os campos input radio. Pensei em usar JS, porém não funcionou. Como dito no tópico, são diversos campos que preciso validar.
segue o código que tenho para ser validado:

```
    <h1 class="topico-titulo" ><?php echo"$nome";?></h1>                
                                <?php 
    $sql="select * from questoes where id_materia=$materia order by rand() limit 10";
                                    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);?>
                                    <div style="margin-left: -28px;margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px;" >


 <form name="simulado" action="correcao.php" method="post">
 <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
    <?php $i = 0; ?>

   <?php while($vetor = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)): ?>

 <?php list($id, $pergunta, $imagem, $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $resposta, $resolucao) = $vetor; ?>

<li> <fieldset  >
  <legend >Questão <?= $i+1; ?></legend>
 <legend > <i>cod.<?= $id; ?></i> </legend>
  <p > <?= $pergunta; ?></p>
  <?php if(!empty($imagem)) { $arquivo = substr($imagem, -3); if($arquivo=='jpg'){?>
  <center>
  <p > <img src="Imagens/<?php echo $imagem; ?>" width="80%" heigth="70%"/>     </p>
  <?php }}?></center>
  <?php $_SESSION['pergunta'.$i]=$pergunta; ?>
  <?php $_SESSION['resolucao'.$i]=$resolucao; ?>
         <input type="hidden" name="questao[<?= $i; ?>]"    value"<?php echo $pergunta; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="id[<?= $i; ?>]"          value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
         <input type="hidden" name="resposta[<?= $i; ?>]"    value="<?php echo $resposta; ?>">
         <ul style="list-style-type:none;margin-left:-6%;">
  <li> <label><input type="radio"  name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="A"> <?= $a; ?></label><br/> </li>
  <li> <label><input type="radio"  name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="B"> <?= $b; ?></label><br/></li>
  <li> <label><input type="radio"  name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="C"> <?= $c; ?></label><br/></li>
  <li> <label><input type="radio"  name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="D"> <?= $d; ?></label><br/></li>
  <li> <label><input type="radio"  name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="E"> <?= $e; ?></label></li>
  </ul>
 </fieldset></li> 

 <?php $i++; ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <input type="submit" name="corrigir" value="Corrigir Simulado">

   </form>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Toda tentativa de ajuda será válida e reconhecida, caso não tenha ficado muito claro meu objetivo, por favor, comentem e exemplificarei e esclarecerei quaisquer dúvidas.

Desde já, muito grato!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode resolver este problema utilizando o atributo `required` do próprio **HTML5**, você só precisa colocar em um `input` que os outros do mesmo grupo irão adotar o mesmo.

[Veja uma questão similar no stackoverflow global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287779/html5-how-to-use-the-required-attribute-with-a-radio-input-field)

Comment: não entendi muito bem, como que eu iria saber se um do grupo de 5 botões foi selecionado, dentre outros 10 grupos? poderia me exemplificar com um código?

Comment: @Dwcleb quando você for criar o grupo de radio, você irá nomear todos com o mesmo atributo `name=""` mas com o atributo `value=""` diferentes, se apenas um desses `input` tiver o atributo `required=""` do **HTML5** então ele se tornará obrigatório. por exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/2du3s/1/

Comment: Na verdade, o erro dele é não colocar ``name`` igual nos radios (que eu também cometo sempre). Outra: é bom indicar o grau de compatibilidade do atributo required: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation

Comment: exatamente @Daniel

Comment: @RafaelRN, o nome teve que ser do jeito que está, eu consegui solucionar o problema já... Na página de correção eu fui chamando os nomes deles... a cada questão, que no total são 10, o nome deles muda a numeração. Deu p eu corrigir usando um loop e verificando o banco de dados, Obrigado pessoal!